# Assignment of Variables to a Record Collection Variable in Salesforce Flow

Tags: automation, salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-flow

I have a screen flow, where there are few screen elements. I am assigning them to different variables. Can I store them altogetjer in a record collection variable? If yes, then how can I do it? If no, then what approach shall I a take to store them as this screen would be looped multiple times and after that I need to insert them in an Object.

TIA.